# Trying to install OpenFL - haxelib returns invalid operation

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxelib

I'm trying to install OpenFL in a windows system. I have already installed haxe but when I run `haxelib install openfl` in command prompt, haxelib returns `Invalid operation(+)`. Any ideas about how can this problem be solved?

Comment: Does running "haxelib" on it's own work? If not, please provide the full error message. Otherwise, can you install other haxelibs? Or run other commands like "haxelib search" etc?

Comment: If I just type 'haxelib' in the windows command prompt, it seems to be ok as it produces a list with the corresponding paramaters. But if I add any parameter (for e.g. 'haxelib install openfl' or 'haxelib info' or 'haxelib search' etc, it returns 'Invalid operation (+)'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is most likely related to haxelib/neko trying to add two null strings.

I have encountered an issue before with Jenkins, since Jenkins removes HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH from the env-vars while doing a build. You may be encountering something similar.

Check and make sure HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH are set in your current shell, the re-try haxelib. If this does not work, we'll have to narrow down further.

Comment: My environmental variables in my windows xp system are:

HAXEPATH: C:\HaxeToolkit\haxe\
NEKO_INSTPATH: C:\HaxeToolkit\neko
PATH: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_04\bin\javaw.exe;%HAXEPATH%;%NEKO_INSTPATH%

Still the same problem.

Comment: What about HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH?

Comment: I created these two environmental variables and it works :) Thank you very much :)

Comment: @MatthewSpencer correct answer and a [pull request](https://github.com/HaxeFoundation/haxelib/pull/94) - you legend!

Comment: @Puma what did you set `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` to?